# How can I add an addon to the google docs side pannel?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Is there any way for developers to add icons to the side panel? The documentation I've seen only shows custom side-bars and the addon ui menu, but the built-in side panel is fairly new and has a button to add add-ons, suggesting that addons would be added to it.

[image]

I'd like to add an icon to the built-in side panel to avoid extra clicks for my add-on.

[UI Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html)
[Custom Sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `sheets` in the addOns section of the manifest, as specified [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-manifests). The documentation for add-ons is available at https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview

Here's a simplified example derived from [Quickstart: Cats Google Workspace Add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/cats-quickstart)

#### Code.gs

```
function onHomepage(e) {
  return CardService.newCardBuilder().addSection(
    CardService.newCardSection().setHeader('Header').addWidget(
      CardService.newTextParagraph().setText('Paragraph')
    )
  ).build();
}
```

#### appsscript.json (manifest)

```
{
  "timeZone": "Etc/GMT",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Cats",
      "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/pets_black_48dp.png",
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onHomepage",
        "enabled": true
      }
    },
    "sheets": {}
  }
}
```

The `homepageTrigger` doesn't need to be in the common section. You could include place it directly within `sheets` instead.