# After the installation of google sheets add-on how to remove google add-on icon?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on

I have developed a google sheets add-on. I deployed the add-on using Manifest and then installed it from my account. I want functionality that when I open any sheet a simple menu appears of installed add-on in the sheet add-on menu.

My manifest looks like this :

[image]

Now, after the installation when I open any sheet, my add-on logo appears but when I try to open it then it shows "content not available for this message".

[image]

I want to remove this add-on icon from the right-side panel because it not showing anything. It is possible to add a custom menu that is available to all sheets after the installation of the add-on.

I want functionality like :

[image]

Comment: does this help or gives you an idea? : [How can I add an addon to the google docs side pannel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65858484/how-can-i-add-an-addon-to-the-google-docs-side-pannel)

Comment: Not possible....